# Can't set an options menu on a MvxFragment with MvvmCross 5

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

### Objective

I have a MainView with a bottom navigation that each element shows a different Fragment. **I want to show an options menu on one of the fragments**, but not on the others.

### The problem

All the examples I read use `SetHasOptionsMenu(true)` on the OnCreate override, but it `doesn't exists in the current context`

Comment: Have you tried `HasOptionsMenu = true;`? For Xamarin Android it has been mapped to a property.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. If you answer the question I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Android.App.Fragment` then you must use the method (MvvmCross equivalent `MvvmCross.Droid.Views.Fragments.MvxFragment`)

```
public class Myfragment :  Android.App.Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        SetHasOptionsMenu(true);

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

If you are using `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` form the support libraries then you must use the property (MvvmCross equivalent `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxFragment`)

```
public class Myfragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        HasOptionsMenu = true;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```